# Angular Compile error with stream-chat-js package. No exported member 'Client'

Tags: node.js, angular, getstream-io

I am getting this error when trying to compile an Angular application with the Node version of the Stream Chat package.

```
ERROR in node_modules/getstream/types/getstream/index.d.ts(12,11): error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/.../app/node_modules/stream-chat/types/stream-chat/index"' has no exported member 'Client'.
```

This error refers to this function from the file reference above:

```
/**
 * Create StreamClient
 */
export function connect(
  apiKey: string,
  apiSecret: string | null,
  appId: string,
  options?: object,
): stream.Client;
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bug when using both Stream Chat and Stream Notification Feeds
See this closed issue: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/issues/258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed with the release of stream-chat v1.8.